# Installing the ahkab packages of Python

Tags: python, pip

I've one problem, when I try to install the 'ahkab' packages on Linux, Ubuntu based, for Python with the command pip (*pip install ahkab*).

You can to see my problem on image below. I don't know what do I need to do to solve this case.
[image]

Comment: making link to include as image

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to run with super user permission while installing.
Use `sudo` in-front of you command.